# Android Activity isn't getting started from Parse Notification

Tags: parse-platform, push, android-notifications

I'm having an odd problem with Parse notifications on Android.

It occurs only in the situation where the application isn't running, a notification is received and the application is started. The first notification will correctly start the default push callback activity however any subsequent notifications do NOT start the activity! This is making the notifications impossible to detect.

When the application is started from it's icon the callback activities are correctly started and I see the onCreate function called. However when it is started from the icon this fails.

I've correctly added all the permissions and application manifest additions. I've specified the following class as the application which initialises the Parse API and sets the callback.

```
package com.distriqt.example.test;

import android.app.Application;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainApplication extends Application 
{
    public static String PARSE_APPLICATION_ID   = "XXXX";
    public static String PARSE_CLIENT_KEY       = "YYYY";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.setLogLevel( Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG );

        Parse.initialize( this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY );
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback( this, ParseCallbackActivity.class );
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

My callback activity looks like the following. I'm basically starting the main package activity and I do some processing on the notification here, before finishing the activity immediately.

```
package com.distriqt.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ParseCallbackActivity extends Activity
{
    public static String TAG = ParseCallbackActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        Log.d( TAG, "onCreate()" );

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent mainAppIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage( getPackageName() );
        mainAppIntent.putExtras( getIntent().getExtras() );
        mainAppIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT );
        startActivity( mainAppIntent );

        printIntent( getIntent() );

        finish();
    }
    public static void printIntent( Intent intent )
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d( TAG, "action = " + intent.getAction() );
            if (intent.getExtras() != null)
            {
                String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));


                Log.d( TAG, "==============================================");
                Log.d( TAG, String.format( "channel:    %s", channel ));
                Log.d( TAG, String.format( "json:       %s", json ));
                Log.d( TAG, "==============================================");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The MainActivity has nothing more than an example layout at the moment. I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

You declared the activity notification in your AndroidManifest.xml?